# SQL Query Returns DataType Mismatch in Query - Why?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a very simple SQL Query here - the point is to look through the Invoice Descriptions and flag the invoice if it is not a valid state. Below is my code and functions:

Query:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Processing " & _
"SET [Invoice Flag] = True " & _
"WHERE isValidState(getState([Inv Description])) = False"
```

getState From Invoice Description to split string of invoice description

```
Public Function getState(description As String) As String
    Dim s() As String
    s = Split(description, ".")
    If (UBound(s) > 1) Then
        getState = s(UBound(s) - 1)
    Else
        getState = " "
    End If
End Function
```

IsValidState To return boolean if a valid state or not

```
Public Function isValidState(st As String) As Boolean
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblStates", dbOpenSnapshot)
    rs.FindFirst ("StateCode = '" & st & "'")
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        isValidState = False
    Else
        isValidState = True
    End If
    rs.Close
End Function
```

Any clues or help is appreciated. I see this error occurs a lot when it comes to Dates, but that isn't the case here. The data records might have some rows that are null - so maybe that has something to do with it? Either way, I can't do anything about those empty descriptions - nor do I se how that should play a factor. Since there is an IF/ELSE statement it should simply return the boolean and flag the invoice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [Inv Description] can be `Null` then you can't declare your function as

```
Public Function getState(description As String) As String
```

you need to declare it as

```
Public Function getState(description As Variant) As String
```

and then handle the Null case using something like

```vbs
If IsNull(description) Then
    getState = ""  ' or whatever
Else
    ' remaining code as before
```

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshoot the SQL error by starting with a `SELECT` rather than an `UPDATE` statement.  Create a new query, switch to SQL View, and paste in this SQL:

```
SELECT
    *,
    getState(Nz([Inv Description],'')) AS state_code
FROM Processing
WHERE
    isValidState(getState(Nz([Inv Description],''))) = False
```

That `Nz()` expression will transform a Null `[Inv Description]` to a string, which is demanded by your `getState()` function.  (Null is **not** a string.)

If it works without error, revise your `UPDATE` query to use the same `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!  Good to know, I was always under the impression that a String could be null =/ Hence if you Dim x As String you have a null String? Maybe I'm just still a newbie or something. Anyhow, thank you!

Comment: An empty string ("zero-length string") is sometimes called a "Null string" ... in fact there is even a VBA named constant, *vbNullString* ... but it is not the same as Null.  This issue confuses folks, but once you understand the difference, you will remember it for a loooong time.  :-)